# HBase Region servers will not start in Hadoop HA environment

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

I've created an HBase cluster in a Hadoop HA cluster. My region servers are failing to start with the following exception in the logs:

```
2017-09-12 11:41:32,116 ERROR [regionserver/my.hostname.com/10.10.30.28:16020] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed init
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument; Host Details : local host is: "my.hostname.com/10.10.30.28"; destination host is: "0.0.0.1":8020;
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by the hadoop HA configuration
I think Hbase doesn't understand the nameservice and thinks it's an IP address.

### excerpt from core-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://001</value>
    <description>NameNode URI</description>
  </property>
```

### excerpt from hdfs-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>001</value>
  </property>
```

### my hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://001/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake. Hbase was missing the path to the hadoop configuration files. Simply added HADOOP_CONF_DIR to hbase-env.sh